# generate jinternalframes on the fly

Tags: java, swing, jinternalframe

I'm looking for a way to generate a jinternalframe with some objects inside (text fields) programatically, but still be able to access the fields.

I know I need to create the jframe as an object, then perhaps have a method inside the object that can poll the parent for updates?

As a real simple example, I've created the following app to show what I'm trying to do. Button 1 and 2 spawn a jinternalframe with a textbox, then I'm stuck at making button 3 and 4 fill in some text into the text box.

```
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    spawnwindow("Window1");
}                                        

private void jButton2ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    spawnwindow("window2");
}                                        

private void jButton3ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
    //todo put data into jTextField2 in window 1
}                                        

private void jButton4ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         
   //todo put data into jTextField2 in window 2
}                                        


    public void spawnwindow(String windowname){

    jInternalFrame3 = new javax.swing.JInternalFrame();
    jTextField2 = new javax.swing.JTextField();

    jInternalFrame3.setName(windowname);

    jInternalFrame3.setVisible(true);

    jTextField2.setText(windowname);

    jInternalFrame3.setTitle(windowname);

    javax.swing.GroupLayout jInternalFrame3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jInternalFrame3.getContentPane());
    jInternalFrame3.getContentPane().setLayout(jInternalFrame3Layout);
    jInternalFrame3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
        jInternalFrame3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jInternalFrame3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 216, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );
    jInternalFrame3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
        jInternalFrame3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
        .addGroup(jInternalFrame3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jTextField2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 134, Short.MAX_VALUE)
            .addContainerGap())
    );

    jInternalFrame3.setBounds(230, 220, 250, 190);
    jDesktopPane1.add(jInternalFrame3, javax.swing.JLayeredPane.DEFAULT_LAYER);        


}
```

Comment: Best option.  Create a sub class that contains the fields you need, with setters and getters.  I would use a `JPanel` as the base form and then add it to the `JInternalFrame` when you need it

Comment: Can you give me a bit more info? perhaps an example code?

Comment: Depending on your needs. Create yourself a custom JPanel, add all the fields you would need, including any setters/getters and listeners. From there, simply instantiate it when you need it and add it to a JInternalFrame

Comment: Thanks, that sounds like what I need. I never thought of doing it that way!